# Putting network interface in promiscuous mode (not monitor mode)

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, raspberry-pi, network-interface

I'm looking to capture Wifi request probes *while still associated with a network* and otherwise not affecting that connection.

I can successfully enable monitor mode but, of course, can't join networks while in monitor mode.

I'm assuming that a network interface that supports monitor mode likely support promiscuous mode too, is that an unreasonable expectation?

I've tried running `tshark` on the interface while associated to a network (it seems `tshark` makes an attempt to set the hardware in promiscuous mode), but that doesn't capture the packets I'm looking for.

How do I put a wireless interface in promiscuous mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I don't know how dependent this answer is on specific hardware.

`airmon-ng` will enable a monitor interface without disrupting your wifi connection.  Install `aircrack-ng` then run something like (I'm assuming wlan0 here):

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Which will typically create a `mon0` interface to the same physical card.

You can also try to do it with `iw` (I'm assuming you are using phy0 here):

```
sudo iw dev #this will show you the relation between phy's and interfaces
sudo iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
```

Where you will create a `mon0` interface to the same physical card.  See (http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw/#Adding_interfaces_with_iw) for more details on using `iw`.

As far as hardware goes, I usually run Atheros cards, but I've seen both of these techniques work on Broadcom cards as well, with the notable difference that when I had a `mon0` interface to a broadcom card, `airodump-ng` couldn't change the channel.

Comment: Yes, I know. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but I successfully used `airmon-ng` to set the interface to monitor mode. That works fine. I'm looking to put the card in promiscuous mode, not monitor mode.

Comment: So just now, I set `wlan1` on my computer down, ran `airmon-ng wlan1`, which created `mon0`, ran `sudo airodump-ng mon0` to start collecting, then ran `wpa_supplicant` (because I don't like network managers) to connect to a wifi network.  I am monitoring on `mon0` but it is not affecting my `wlan1`.  Isn't that what you are looking for?  If it isn't working for you, what network manager and hardware are you using?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that it was I'm trying to do. When I run `airmon-ng`, the `wlan0` interface gets replaced with `wlan0mon`. The original `wlan0` interface is no longer available. If I use `wpa_supplicant` to connect with `wlan0mon`, the dump collection stops.

Comment: Have you tried the `iw` technique?  I ask because I'm pretty sure that the `airmon-ng` source code is actually just a bash script that goes through and tries a bunch of things.  It likely tries the `iw` technique but fails out and tries something else.  I think if you manually run the `iw` technique and it gives you an error, you might be up against a hardware limitation. ... Oh! Also run `iw phy` and under the "supported commands" see if there's a `new_interface` command supported.

Comment: Wow, that works. Phenomenal. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ip link set wlan0 promisc on
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't behave any differently, nor do I see any errors.

Comment: Oh, but `netstat -i` does show the interface flags as `BMPRU`, where the `P` stands for promiscuous.

Comment: Promiscuous mode means the kernel or network card won't drop packages that aren't addressed to your network card; however, it does not mean that such packages will be sent to your network card, or (if you're using wpa2) that they'll be encrypted to your network card.